# How to put public IP address directly on EC2 Instance network card

Tags: amazon-ec2

When I create a machine on Amazon AWS it always comes with Public and Private IP.

I need to have the public IP directly on the server's network card.

It's possible?

Comment: I am not sure I understood the question, but you can assign a public IP to the ENI and the attach the ENI to the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. What AWS does, is a mapping from public IP address to the primary private IP address using network address translation (NAT). They actually don't assign a public IP address to EC2 instances.

More info [AWS Doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/using-instance-addressing.html#concepts-public-addresses)

Comment: Correct. The Internet Gateway performs reverse-NAT, redirecting any traffic destined for the Public IP address to the Private IP address. The instance does not actually need to know that it has a public IP address.